# Are studentized deleted residuals &/or DFfits applicable in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, residuals

Are [studentized deleted residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual) and [DFfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFFITS) applicable in logistic regression? In some statistical packages (Stata for example) these statistics are available in linear regression analysis, but not in the logistic regression. It makes me think that studentized deleted residuals and DFfits are not applicable in logistic regression. But many literature sources say the opposite: it is possible and necessary in logistic regression.

**Would it be correct to calculate these statistics in logistic regression?**